# Retrieve df from spark.sql : [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm using a databricks notebook and I'd like to retrieve a dataframe from an SQL execution in Spark. I have:

```
statement = f""" USER {db}; SELECT * FROM {table}
"""

df = spark.sql(statement)
display(df)
```

However, unlike when I fire off the same statement in an SQL cell in the notebook, I get the following error:

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'SELECT': extra input 'SELECT'(line 1...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results**:*

*This my sample demo table `Persons`.*

[image]

*Create dataframe by using this code as shown in the below image.*

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from Persons")
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. However even when using sqlContext.sql I get the same error message. I'm looking into whether the "use" is causing an issue.

Comment: I have tried with db and got same error https://i.imgur.com/mSCj2ge.png. Don't use `use db;` while selecting using spark sql. It automatically detects the schema.

Comment: Instead of using `db`, you can do like this https://i.imgur.com/e1DItKv.png

Comment: I had to use without "use", also the dataframe returned is a pyspark one, so I had to use df = df.toPandas() to make the conversion. Thanks