# printSchema() working good in the Dataframe , after applying filter, display() Not working in Azure Synapse notebook why?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm getting columns from Azure SQL Database to Synapse Analytics Notebook.

Have created a Dataframe can Able to see all white space columns with help of display(df_InventorySnapshot),

One of the Column name "Project Number", I need to handle Filter isNotNull(). \

After applying this logic in the dataframe It's ran successfully and able to see all columns structure with datatypes help of printSchema().

But I'm not able to use "Display(df_InventorySnapshotFilter)".

It's throwing a error I attached the screen shot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: can you provide the code for Display(df_InventorySnapshotFilter)?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleDataFrame").getOrCreate()
schema02 = StructType([
StructField("Project number", IntegerType(), True), # Allow null values with True
StructField("business area", StringType(), True),
StructField("project name", StringType(), True),
StructField("product line segment", StringType(), True)
])
data02 = [
(1, 'Finance', 'Project A', 'Segment X'),
(2, 'Marketing', 'Project B', 'Segment Y'),
(None, 'HR', None, 'Segment Z'),
(4, None, 'Project D', None),
(5, 'Operations', 'Project E', None)
]
Project_lookup_df = spark.createDataFrame(data02, schema=schema02)
df_project_lookup_details_select = Project_lookup_df.select(
col("`Project number`"),
col("`business area`"),
col("`project name`"),
col("`product line segment`")
)
df_project_look_details_rename = df_project_lookup_details_select\
.withColumnRenamed("business area","project Business Area")\
.filter(col("`Project number`").isNotNull())
display(df_project_look_details_rename)
df_filterprojlookdetail = df_project_look_details_rename\
.filter(df_project_lookup_details_select["Project number"].isNotNull())
display(df_filterprojlookdetail)
```

[image]
I have tried the above code And for the error.
Parse exception syntax at or near **Number**: extra input near number
You can try using the dataframe to in **sqlContext.sql**

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from Persons")
display(df)
```

And also you can refer the solution for the similar ERROR.

Here is the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798965/retrieve-df-from-spark-sql-parse-syntax-error-syntax-error-at-or-near-selec)